# matlab AND excel AND indexing

Tags: excel, matlab, loops, indexing

I have four files, each which I have to extract two columns.

```
Data21 = xlsread('Data21','Hits'); %% the files are names Data21/22/23/24 
Hits = Data21(:,[4,15])
Data21 = xlsread('Data21','FA'); 
FA = Data21(:,[4,15]);
FA(FA == 4) = 0 ;
Cond21 = [FA,Hits]
```

I can't seem to use a count to get this to work on a loop. Does anyone have suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is unanswerable as it is. Please give more information, and / or the errors you're getting. What do you want to loop over exactly. Files? Columns? What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go on the assumption you want to loop *files* and don't know how to create a loop that generates filenames.

You can create such an iteration over filenames using sprintf, e.g.:

```
for i = [21 : 24]
  filename = sprintf ('Data%d', i);
  Data = xlsread (filename, 'Hits');
  % ... etc, etc.
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my badly worded question. Much appreciated